# Algebraic Topology; Hatcher 2.23

Tags: algebraic-topology

Example 2.23 from Hatcher starts by stating...

*Let us find explicit cycles representing generators of the infinite cyclic groups $H_n(D^n,\partial D^n)$ and $\tilde{H}(S^n)$.  Replacing $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ by the equivalent pair $(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$, we will show by induction on $n$ that the identity map $i_n:\Delta^n\to \Delta^n$, viewed as a singular $n$-simplex, is a cycle generating $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$.  **That it is a cycle is clear since we are considering relative homology.  When $n=0$ it certainly represents a generator.***

Now, the  part I don't understand is the easy part, the stuff in bold.  How is the identity map a cycle and a generator when n=0?  Is there an example of a map from $\Delta^n\to \Delta^n$ that is not a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewing it as a singular simplex, the identity $i_n: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ is a cycle by the definition of singular homology: its boundary $\partial i_n$ is sum with the alternating signs of the inclusions $\Delta^{n-1} \to \Delta^{n}$ of the $n-1$-simplex onto the faces of the $n$-simplex, so it can be viewed as a singular simplex in $\partial \Delta^n$.

This is zero in relative homology, because it is already zero on the relative chain level: indeed, the relative homology is defined by a homology of a chain complex fitting in the following short exact sequence of chain complexes:

$$
0 \to C(\partial \Delta^n) \to C(\Delta^n) \to C(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \to 0
$$

$\partial i_n \in C_n(\Delta^n)$ is mapped to zero in $ C(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$, because it belongs to $C(\partial \Delta^n)$ as well, which is the kernel of the map $C(\Delta^n) \to C(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$.

For $n = 0$, the $\Delta^0$ is a single point space $*$, so the inclusion $i_0: \Delta^0 \to \Delta^0$ represents a generator of $H_0(\Delta^0, \partial \Delta^0) = H_0(*, \emptyset) = H_0(*)$ by the calculation of $H_0(X)$ of any space earlier in Hatcher (Hatcher proves that $H_0(X)$ is a free group generated by the classes of maps $* \to X$ into different path-connected components).

Comment: Thanks!  So if I understand, a less precise way to say that $i_n$ is a cycle would be; $\Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^n\stackrel{i_n}{\to} X\implies \Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^n\to \Delta^n$ means that $i_n$ is a cycle because $\Delta^{n-1}$ is bounded by $\Delta^n$

Comment: I don't really understand your less precise way :) Less  precisely, I'd just say that a chain $s \in C(X, A)$ is a cycle precisely when its boundary lies inside $A$. Usually it's not easy to see instantly what's a boundary of a chain, but in our case it's pretty trivial.

Comment: OK, I get it.  I'll try one more time to rephrase the idea though.  I suppose what I was trying to say is, since the simplex is trivial and a map from $\Delta^n\to \Delta^n$, we are guaranteed that the faces of $\Delta^n$ (i.e. $\Delta^{n-1}$) are bounded by $\Delta^n$

Comment: I still don't understand your point. Every cycle $C(\Delta^n)$ is a boundary (because $\Delta^n$ is contractible), but this is no longer true for relative chains $C(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$.

Comment: Let's even consider a special case: consider a continuous map $f: \Delta^1 \to \Delta^1$. Let $e_0, e_1$ be the vertices of $\Delta^1$. Then, viewing $f$ as a member of $C_1(\Delta^1)$, the boundary $\partial f \in C_0(\Delta^1)$, $\partial f = a -b$ where $a, b: \Delta_0 \to \Delta_1$, $a(e_0) = f(e_1)$, $b(e_0) = f(e_0)$. We see thus that $f$ is a cycle iff $\partial f = 0$ iff $a = b$ iff $f(e_0) = f(e_1)$, that is, $f$ is a loop.